# Subsets $A_i$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $|A_i\cap A_j| = (i,j)$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Here is a problem that I can not solve. Any suggestion or hint would be helpful. If there is a history of this problem in the literature please let me know.

Does there exists subsets $A_1, A_2, \cdots$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that for any two (not necessary different) natural numbers $i,j$, $|A_i\cap A_j| = (i,j)$ ? (Where $(i,j)$ is the greatest common divisor of $i$ and $j$.) As joriki also pointed out, this implies that $|A_k|=k$ for all $k$.

Comment: $|A_i\cap A_j|$ is a cardinality, a number; $(i,j)$ is ... a pair of numbers? An interval?

Comment: $(i, j)$ is sometimes used as a notation for the greatest common divisor of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: or may be gcd of i and j??

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen (i,j) is the greatest common divisor of i and j.

Comment: Its okay to downvote a ploblem but it would be helpful if you write the reason.

Comment: So in particular $|A_k|=k$?

Comment: @joriki thats right.

Comment: There are two possible reasons for the downvotes: First it was initially unclear with respect to the notation $(i, j)$. Second, it does not provide any context. Questions are far better received if you tell us where the problem comes from, what you tried so far so solve it (perhaps some partial results?) etc.

Comment: What others said about context. You could share with us your history of the problem! How did you come to think about this? I'm curious about the reason :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jyrki just posted a far more elegant proof than the one I was about to write up, but I'll post it anyway, in case you're interested in a proof with a more combinatorial flavour.

Yes, such subsets exist. We can prove this by an inductive construction. For $k\in\mathbb N$, let $b_k$ be the number of elements that $A_k$ is constrained to contain due to its overlaps with sets $A_j$ with $j\lt k$, so that we're left free to choose $c_k=k-b_k$ additional elements that don't appear in any of the $A_j$. We need to prove $c_k\ge0$.

Consider the [prime factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) $k=\prod_{i=1}^dp_i^{n_i}$. By [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) on the [lattice of divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Examples) of $k$, we have

$$
c_k=\sum_{\epsilon\in\{0,1\}^d}(-1)^{\sum_i\epsilon_i}\frac k{\prod_ip_i^{\epsilon_i}}=k\prod_i\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)\;,
$$

which is clearly positive. Note that this is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), which counts the number of positive integers up to $k$ that are coprime with $k$, and that this is precisely the number of solutions to $z^k=1$ in Jyrki's answer that are not solutions to any equation $z^m=1$ with $m\lt k$.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: What if $A_k$ were the set of complex numbers $z$ such that $z^k=1$?

Comment: Leaving "a hint" only as requested. I am aware of the fact that the question has a few shortcomings. I believe the OP can fix them, so I post this anyway. In other words, [I was nerd sniped](https://www.xkcd.com/356/).

Comment: The accepted answer was just switched to mine -- just wanted to let you know that in my view, yours deserved it much more :-)

Comment: Thanks, @joriki. It's the asker's call to make. Doesn't matter much, we're both in six digits :-)